# Mosonry Gallery Images doen't display correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, masonry

I'm following John Edler's Ruby on Rails tutorial. When I render the App initial looks just fine, however when I start to click Home or the brand on the navigation bar, all the images(pins) displays back to vertically, but every time refresh the browser it looks fine again but it not. I'm not sure what the problem is, hoping somebody would help me out.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
```

**application.scss**

```
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

**...view/pins/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render '/home/jumbo' unless user_signed_in? %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
    <% @pins.each do |pin| %>

        <div class="box">  
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %><br/>
                <div class="panel-body">
                <%= pin.description %><br/>
                <%= pin.user.name if pin.user %><br/>
                <% if pin.user==current_user %>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin), class:'btn btn-primary' %>
                  <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, class:'btn btn-primary', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %><br/>
               </div>
                <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**...view/home/_header.html.erb**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <div class="navbar-nav">

      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to 'Tsarong', pins_path, class:"navbar-brand"%></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %> </li>
        <li><%= link_to 'About App', home_about_path %></li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
          <li><%= link_to 'Add Pin', new_pin_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'List Pins', pins_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete  %></li>
        <% else %>    
          <li><%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Join', new_user_registration_path%></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Your help is very appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off turbolinks in your application. Maybe you get an error, because masonry script doesn't properly handle turbolink reload:

1. Remove the gem `turbolinks` line from your Gemfile.
2. Remove the `//= require turbolinks` from your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.
3. Remove the two `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` hash key/value pairs from your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: Glad to hear this. Marking my answer as a correct one with green tick would be the best thanks from you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - Anton Tkachov!
I removed the gem turbolinks line from the Gemfile and removed //=require turbolinks from app/assets/javascripts/application.js. 
Now it works!!! Thanks!